# How to make a textbox appear in Minecraft Bedrock

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, minecraft-addons

Does anyone know how to add a text box like this one here (shown in image) into Minecraft Bedrock? Either with Vanilla or Addons.
I would not need the clickable menus but only the text.

[image: Example of what I mean by Textbox]

Comment: It is definitely not possible in vanilla, and I don’t think it is in addons either (however I think a similar thing could be achieved)

Comment: @Penguin How was it achieved in the pictured example?

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 thats a featured server tho

Comment: @Penguin So those textboxes are attainable only by Mojang?

Comment: ? I... didn't say that? What I'm saying is this is **not achievable via commands** and servers obviously **don't have everyone download a behavior and resource pack.** I think this works the same way that custom entities in servers do

Comment: @Penguin Would you be able to let me know how the custom entity thing works?

Comment: Sorry i dont know, But i do know you need a server (not the dedicated one from the minecraft site) to do it

Answer (score 2):

## Use NPCs

I know it’s a bit late, but your best bet to display a text box would probably be to use NPCs.

1. Run the command `/give @s spawn_egg 1 51`.
2. Open the NPC UI.
3. Click “Edit Dialogue”
4. Enter the text you want to display.

If you *do* want to have clickable buttons (up to six), you can click “Add Command” and check the button mode option.